# Problem in time shown by PC

Tags: dual-boot

Since I loaded Ubuntu 14.04 and Windows8.1 on my PC, the desktop of none of them keeps proper time. I tried setting the time many times but it is not maintained when I switch on my PC after some time. Please help

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to replace the battery for your CMOS BIOS on your motherboard.